# How to keep first observation and delete other observations of each group in unbalanced Panel data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge panel data. I want to create a new data keeping only first observation of each group. How can I achieve it? For illustrative purpose;

```
mydata = {{1, a, aa}, {1, b, bb}, {1, c, cc}, {2, d, dd}, {2, e, 
    ee}, {3, f, ff}, {3, g, gg}, {3, h, hh}, {4, i, ii}, {4, j, 
    jj}, {4, k, kk}, {4, l, ll}, {4, m, mm}, {5, n, nn}, {5, o, 
    oo}, {7, p, pp}};
```

My final result should be:

```
myanswer = {{1, a, aa}, {2, d, dd}, {3, f, ff}, {4, i, ii}, {5, n, 
    nn}, {7, p, pp}};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/@`):

```
First /@ GatherBy[mydata, First]

(* {{1, a, aa}, {2, d, dd}, {3, f, ff}, {4, i, ii}, {5, n, nn}, {7, p, pp}} *)
```

You could also use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (`[[]]`) to get the first element of each group.

```
GatherBy[mydata, First][[All,1]]
```

Comment: Oops! Typing too fast – thanks bel!

Comment: @ Verbeia thank you for your answer. I did not know it was that simple.

Answer (score 5):

```
 First /@  Split[mydata, #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &]
```

Comment: @ belisarius, thank you as always. Its that simple.