# How to extract both first and last rows of each group from unbalanced panel data

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

This is a follow up question form my last question [click here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66286/how-to-keep-first-observation-and-delete-other-observations-of-each-group-in-unb). I have unbalanced panel data such as :

```
pdata = {{AA, 1, 10}, {AA, 2, 20}, {CC, 3, 30}, {CC, 4, 40}, {CC, 5, 
    50}, {CC, 6, 60}, {CC, 7, 70}, {DD, 8, 80}, {DD, 9, 90}, {DD, 10, 
    100}, {EE, 11, 110}, {EE, 12, 120}, {EE, 13, 130}, {HH, 14, 
    140}, {HH, 15, 150}, {HH, 16, 160}, {HH, 17, 170}, {HH, 18, 
    180}, {HH, 19, 190}, {HH, 20, 200}};
```

I want to extract firs and last rows of each group. Thank to both Verbeia and belisarius. With their help I can write:

```
firstrow = First /@ GatherBy[pdata, First];
lastrow = Last /@ GatherBy[pdata, First];
bothrows = Join @@ Flatten[{firstrow, lastrow}, {{2}, {1}}];
```

and get my desired result. But my actual  data is very big and it takes time if I do this way. I am looking for better and faster way of doing the same. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your data sorted by first entry (i.e., AA, CC, DD, ...)?  And how big is your dataset?  You should be able to extract the required data using the Verbeia and belisarius method for millions of entries within a few seconds.

Comment: is your data in external file? can you import it to mathematics or not?

Comment: @Algohi, the original data is in txt format. However, I have converted to .mat format so that I can read it faster. The data has over 50 columns and over 53m obs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you data is sorted:

```
 Flatten[SplitBy[pdata, #[[1]] &][[All, {1, -1}]], 1]
```

if not:

```
Flatten[GatherBy[pdata, #[[1]] &][[All, {1, -1}]], 1]
```

Comment: Thank you Kuba for taking time to answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Version 10 functions `GroupBy` and `Merge`:

```
Join@@Values@GroupBy[pdata, First, Through@{First,Last}@#&]
```

and

```
Join@@Values@Merge[#->{##}&@@@pdata,Through@{First,Last}@#&]
```

to get

```
(* {{AA, 1, 10}, {AA, 2, 20}, {CC, 3, 30}, {CC, 7, 70}, {DD, 8, 80}, {DD,
   10, 100}, {EE, 11, 110}, {EE, 13, 130}, {HH, 14, 140}, {HH, 20, 200}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks kguler for taking time to answer this question.

Comment: @ramesh, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

```
pdata[[Flatten[
   Values[Map[{#[[1]], #[[-1]]} &, PositionIndex[pdata[[;; , 1]]]]]]]]

(*{{AA, 1, 10}, {AA, 2, 20}, {CC, 3, 30}, {CC, 7, 70}, {DD, 8, 80}, {DD,
   10, 100}, {EE, 11, 110}, {EE, 13, 130}, {HH, 14, 140}, {HH, 20, 
  200}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you Algohi for taking time to answer this question.

Comment: My pleasure :),