# List manipulation - grouping sublists according to their first element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
list1 = {
         {0, 0, 1496.11, 308.593}, {1, 0, 1168.02, 320.9}, {1, 1, 1161.97, 315.926}, 
         {2, 0, 1287.57, 323.834}, {3, 0, 1618.89, 323.874}, {4, 0, 1251.01, 326.575}, 
         {5, 0, 1474.81, 330.69}, {6, 0, 1181.24, 331.692}, {7, 0, 2431.87, 337.616}, 
         {8, 0, 961.105, 340.223}, {9, 0, 1148.98, 344.855}, {9, 1, 1153.03, 336.984}, 
         {10, 0, 1570.98, 346.771}, {11, 0, 1122.66, 349.883}, {11, 1, 1122.34, 351.845}, 
         {11, 2, 1122.63, 353.678}, {11, 3, 1120.75, 351.175}, {11, 4, 1122.24, 358.885}, 
         {11, 5, 1125.73, 360.05}, {11, 6, 1126.43, 362.175}
        }
```

How can I manupulate `list1` to receive `list2` ;

```
list2 = {
         {{0, 0, 1496.11, 308.593}},
         {{1, 0, 1168.02, 320.9}, {1, 1, 1161.97, 315.926}}, 
         {{2, 0, 1287.57, 323.834}}, 
         {{3, 0, 1618.89, 323.874}},
         {{4, 0, 1251.01, 326.575}}, 
         {{5, 0, 1474.81, 330.69}}, 
         {{6, 0, 1181.24, 331.692}}, 
         {{7, 0, 2431.87, 337.616}}, 
         {{8, 0, 961.105, 340.223}}, 
         {{9, 0, 1148.98, 344.855}, {9, 1, 1153.03, 336.984}}, 
         {{10, 0, 1570.98, 346.771}}, 
         {{11, 0, 1122.66, 349.883}, {11, 1, 1122.34, 351.845}, {11, 2, 1122.63, 353.678}, 
          {11, 3, 1120.75, 351.175}, {11, 4, 1122.24, 358.885}, {11, 5, 1125.73, 360.05}, 
          {11, 6, 1126.43, 362.175}}
        }
```

I tried to use a `Do` loop with `If` conditions and `AppendTo` but the code became terribly complicated.

Comment: Another one, using that your list is sorted: `Split[list1, First@#1 == First@#2 &]`

Comment: yes it is sorted according first element of sublists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
GatherBy[list1, First] (* or *)
Values @ GroupBy[list1, First] (* or *)
Values @ Merge[Identity][Association[{# -> {##}}]& @@@ list1]
```

> {{{0, 0, 1496.11, 308.593}},
>   {{1, 0, 1168.02, 320.9}, {1, 1, 1161.97, 
>      315.926}},
>   {{2, 0, 1287.57, 323.834}},
>    {{3, 0, 1618.89, 
>      323.874}},
>   {{4, 0, 1251.01, 326.575}},
>    {{5, 0, 1474.81, 
>      330.69}},
>   {{6, 0, 1181.24, 331.692}},
>    {{7, 0, 2431.87, 
>      337.616}},
>   {{8, 0, 961.105, 340.223}},
>   {{9, 0, 1148.98, 
>      344.855}, {9, 1, 1153.03, 336.984}},
>    {{10, 0, 1570.98, 
>      346.771}},
>   {{11, 0, 1122.66, 349.883}, {11, 1, 1122.34, 
>      351.845}, {11, 2, 1122.63, 353.678}, {11, 3, 1120.75, 
>      351.175}, {11, 4, 1122.24, 358.885}, {11, 5, 1125.73, 360.05}, {11,
>       6, 1126.43, 362.175}}}

Comment: oh no ... I was sure that something short would come out but this is depressing ;-) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lio, my pleasure:)

Comment: Would you consider this a duplicate of [(4332)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121), or [(66286)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66286/121)?  Each is a bit more complicated but this simpler problem is solved in the process.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I am not sure how to treat this kind of cases. Besides. this one feels so familiar that I am almost sure there is a more direct duplicate, but  I couldn't find them with keywords `GroupBy`, `GatherBy`  and `Merge`.

Comment: I looked too, and those were the best I could find.  Maybe simpler questions got closed and deleted as *Easily found in the documentation*?  By the way, any reason you don't lead your answer with `GatherBy`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I made the change (there was no reason:).